# Como colorar meta tags no PDF?

Tags: php

Eu tenho alguns links para PDF's no meu site e eu verifiquei que no google a informação não aparece correcta.

Então a pergunta é: Posso definir a meta descrição e título no PDF?

Com alguma pesquisa em vez de mostrar directamente o link para `CertificadoQAmadeuAntunes.pdf`  comecei por alterar para `CertificadoQAmadeuAntunes.php` e coloquei o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$file = './CertificadoQAmadeuAntunes.pdf';
$filename = 'CertificadoQAmadeuAntunes.pdf'; 
/* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
?>
```

Agora queria colocar as tags "title" "descrição" e "keywords".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bloqueei o PDF no `roboots.txt`

Criei outro ficheiro `.php`

E coloquei o seguinte código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Certificado de Qualificações 12º ano - Amadeu Antunes</title>
<meta name="description" content="Certificado de Qualificações 12º ano e Certifiação Profissional em Técnico de Informática-Sistemas Amadeu Antunes">
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;

height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <iframe src="CertificadoQAmadeuAntunes.pdf"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```